# Three letters, one dial

Tags: riddle, cipher

You, a great scientist, is being held hostage by aliens. They want to test human intelligence and see if the human race is worth to collaborate with.

According to the aliens, if you manage to escape human race will live and be valued as allies.

They give you two items:
-a dial with the whole alphabet
-a note with a human cipher

Note:

```
1=1 1111 1 0 1=1 1111 11=11 1 1 0 11=111 1 1=1 1=1 1 11=11 111 0 11=1 11=11 1 1=11=11=1111 0 1=11=1 11=1 1=11
```

> Type the correct letters into the dial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly via bruteforce (or frequency analysis):

> the three letters ?re? ???

And with correct method, when you could see "1" is "e" and "1=1" is "t":

> When "1=1" is "dash" and "1" is "dot" and "0" is separator/space:
>  - .... .  - .... .-. . .  .-.. . - - . .-. ...  .- .-. . ---...  -- .- -.
>  THE THREE LETTERS ARE: MAN

Comment: Nice, I guess that was too easy.